# How do I fix "theme parsing error" when attempting to launch plank?

Tags: 20.04, plank

Guys I need help because whenever i launch plank or use "plank -d" it shows this message:

```
[DEBUG 16:40:00.291288] [GLib-GIO] _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
[DEBUG 16:40:00.315420] [GLib-GIO] _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’

(plank:26806): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:40:00.358: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:7188:40: Junk at end of value for background-color
[DEBUG 16:40:00.458059] [GLib] unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
[INFO 16:40:00.459287] [AbstractMain:229] Plank version: 0.11.89
[INFO 16:40:00.459376] [AbstractMain:230] Kernel version: 5.4.0-54-generic
[INFO 16:40:00.459461] [AbstractMain:231] GLib version: 2.64.3 (2.61.2)
[INFO 16:40:00.459543] [AbstractMain:234] GTK+ version: 3.24.20 (3.24.10)
[INFO 16:40:00.459624] [AbstractMain:237] Wnck version: 3.32.0
[INFO 16:40:00.459718] [AbstractMain:238] Cairo version: 1.16.0
[INFO 16:40:00.459802] [AbstractMain:239] Pango version: 1.44.7
[INFO 16:40:00.459881] [AbstractMain:240] + Cairo/Gtk+ HiDPI support enabled
[INFO 16:40:00.459961] [AbstractMain:242] + Dynamic Quicklists support enabled
[INFO 16:40:00.460043] [AbstractMain:245] + XInput Barriers support enabled
[INFO 16:40:00.473907] [WindowControl:68] Window-manager: GNOME Shell
[DEBUG 16:40:00.476990] [DockletManager:204] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-applications.so'
[INFO 16:40:00.477245] [DockletManager:107] Docklet 'applications' registered
[DEBUG 16:40:00.478689] [DockletManager:204] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-battery.so'
[INFO 16:40:00.478884] [DockletManager:107] Docklet 'battery' registered
[DEBUG 16:40:00.480348] [DockletManager:204] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-clippy.so'
[INFO 16:40:00.480556] [DockletManager:107] Docklet 'clippy' registered
[DEBUG 16:40:00.482074] [DockletManager:204] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-clock.so'
[INFO 16:40:00.482263] [DockletManager:107] Docklet 'clock' registered
[DEBUG 16:40:00.483639] [DockletManager:204] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-cpumonitor.so'
[INFO 16:40:00.483826] [DockletManager:107] Docklet 'cpumonitor' registered
[DEBUG 16:40:00.485239] [DockletManager:204] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-desktop.so'
[INFO 16:40:00.485472] [DockletManager:107] Docklet 'desktop' registered
[DEBUG 16:40:00.486928] [DockletManager:204] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-trash.so'
[INFO 16:40:00.487101] [DockletManager:107] Docklet 'trash' registered
[DEBUG 16:40:00.487218] [GLib] setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
[INFO 16:40:00.487428] [AbstractMain:299] Running with 1 docks ('dock1')
[DEBUG 16:40:00.487566] [DockController:80] Create dock 'dock1' (config_folder = /home/vincent/.config/plank/dock1)
[DEBUG 16:40:00.487643] [GLib] setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
[DEBUG 16:40:00.487871] [Settings:53] Bind 'PlankDockPreferences' to '/net/launchpad/plank/docks/dock1/'

(plank:26806): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:40:00.532: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:7188:40: Junk at end of value for background-color
[DEBUG 16:40:00.636355] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/vincent/.local/share/plank/themes/mcOS-BS-White-Stock/dock.theme'
[DEBUG 16:40:00.640129] [ItemFactory:176] Loading dock elements from '/home/vincent/.config/plank/dock1/launchers'
[DEBUG 16:40:00.641404] [Unity:164] Initializing LauncherEntry support
**
ERROR:arraylist.c:2644:gee_array_list_iterator_real_get: assertion failed: (_index >= 0)
Bail out! ERROR:arraylist.c:2644:gee_array_list_iterator_real_get: assertion failed: (_index >= 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and it doesn't launch when I click on it. can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

> (plank:26806): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:40:00.532: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:7188:40: Junk at end of value for background-color

Is easy to fix. Open the gtk.css file of your current theme (which can be found at either `/usr/share/themes/yourTheme/gtk-3.0` or on you home directory in the `.themes` directory (same subfolders).
Probably a semicolon missing...

**But** this is not the reason for the failure since GTK will resume to its default values.
This seems to be the culprit:

> ERROR:arraylist.c:2644:gee_array_list_iterator_real_get: assertion failed:

Since I'm using Plank myself on a Debian Buster without any problems, it rather seems to be an inconsistent library.
Since you did not mention your desktop and/or Ubuntu Version, I can't help any further.